# How to get coredumpctl to show dumps after reboot?

Tags: linux, systemd

On a Debian stretch server I have installed `systemd-coredump` to save coredumps whenever a program crashes.
This basically works fine. Whenever sth. crashes, the dump is listed in `coredumpctl list` and I can get information about it using `coredumpctl info`.

However, after a reboot `coredumpctl list` is always empty, althogh the files in `/var/lib/systemd/coredump/` are still present.

Is there any way to get `coredumpctl` to show the information again? Is there another tool to inspect the files is `/var/lib/systemd/coredump/`?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The information isn't extracted directly from the coredumps every time; it's done when receiving the dump, then stored in the systemd-journal. Everything you see in *coredumpctl* is merely a reformatted journal message.

This means that the system log messages, too, have to be stored in /var. Create a `/var/log/journal` directory, then make sure journald.conf allows persistent storage (sometimes this needs to be specified explicitly, if the "auto" mode doesn't work).

You can still use the coredump files as-is with *gdb* and other tools – in the end, they're just lz4-compressed standard core dumps that the kernel would generate anyway. (systemd-coredumpctl merely receives and organizes them – not creates them.)

For example, to generate a backtrace you can use gdb's `bt` subcommand.

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5115613/core-dump-file-analysis
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305866/how-to-analyze-a-programs-core-dump-file-with-gdb

Comment: Thank you very much! I actually could get the stack trace with gdb, and I'll try to make the journal more persistent.